DataTables.js: Custom ordering function not applying
I have a DataTables.js table with a column that has numeric values with decimal points. Currently, it's being ordered like "1", "1.1", "10", "2", but I would like to order it as "1", "1.1", "2", "10". Strangely enough, if I click the ordering arrow after the page has loaded, it does order it the way I want. Anyway, according to their documentation, something like this should work:
//Custom ordering function
DataTable.ext.type.order['numeric-decimal-pre'] = function (data) {
    return parseFloat(data) || 0;
};
//Initialize datatable
let table = new DataTable("#@(Model.Id)", {
    columnDefs: [
        {                    
            type: "numeric-decimal",
            targets: 0,
        },
    ],
    order: [[0, "asc"]],
});

However, while no errors are popping up in the console, it's also not changing the ordering in any way.

That was interesting. I had a play and further research into the documentation, and it seems as though you were perhaps invoking order incorrectly or in an older manner, this seems to work:
//Custom ordering function
DataTable.ext.type.order['numeric-decimal-pre'] = function(data) {
  return parseFloat(data) || 0;
};

(() => {
  //Initialize datatable
  const table = new DataTable('#example', {
    columnDefs: [{
      type: "numeric-decimal",
      targets: 6,
    }, ],
    order: [{
      idx: 6,
      dir: 'asc'
    }]
  });
})()

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/bokd3ftj/
However, after further play, you don't need a custom sort filter as this seems to work:
(() => {
  //Initialize datatable
  const table = new DataTable('#example', {
    order: [{
      idx: 6,
      dir: 'asc'
    }]
  });
})()


Thanks for the answer! I can't try it until tomorrow but I'll let you know how it goes when I do.
